# Python: Tkinter Chat Application - I want to draw bubbles around messages

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, chat

I am learning how to use Tkinter to make GUIs. I have created a simple chat application.

I want the chat text (only chat text, not the date and time) to be wrapped in bubbles (or at least, rectangles) like most chat applications (WhatsApp, Messenger, etc.)

I have tried solving the problem for days but I cannot seem to understand how to do it.

Is it possible to do such an edit to my code? (Comments would be massively appreciated so I can learn)

```
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
import textwrap

def send(event):
    getmsg = EntryBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c').strip()
    msg = textwrap.fill(getmsg,30)
    EntryBox.delete("0.0", END)

    if msg != '':
        ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
        ChatLog.insert(END, current_time, ("small","right","colour"))
        ChatLog.insert(END,msg + '\n\n',("right"))

        ChatLog.config(foreground="#0000CC", font=("Helvetica", 9))

        res = "Bot's response goes into here, elongating this message to test textwrap"
        ChatLog.insert(END, current_time, ("small", "colour"))
        ChatLog.insert(END,textwrap.fill(res,30)+'\n\n')

        ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
        ChatLog.yview(END)


def send_by_button():
    getmsg = EntryBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c').strip()
    msg = textwrap.fill(getmsg,30)
    EntryBox.delete("0.0", END)

    if msg != '':
        ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
        ChatLog.insert(END, current_time, ("small","right","colour"))
        ChatLog.insert(END,msg + '\n\n',("right"))

        ChatLog.config(foreground="#0000CC", font=("Helvetica", 9))

        res = "Bot's response goes into here, elongating this message to test textwrap"
        ChatLog.insert(END, current_time, ("small", "colour"))
        ChatLog.insert(END,textwrap.fill(res,30)+'\n\n')

        ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
        ChatLog.yview(END)


# The following two functions are defined to add a placeholder text or to delete it.
def deletePlaceholder(event):
    Placeholder.place_forget()
    EntryBox.focus_set()


def addPlaceholder(event):
    if placeholderFlag == 1:
        Placeholder.place(x=6, y=421, height=70, width=265)


base = Tk()
base.title("Sample Chat")
base.geometry("400x500")
base.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)



#Add menus to the GUI
main_menu = Menu(base)
file_menu = Menu(base)
file_menu.add_command(label="New..")
file_menu.add_command(label="Save As..")
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit")
main_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
#Add the rest of the menu options to the main menu
main_menu.add_command(label="Edit")
main_menu.add_command(label="Quit")
base.config(menu=main_menu)

now = datetime.now()
current_time = now.strftime("%D - %H:%M \n")

# Create Chat window
ChatLog = Text(base, bd=0, height="8", width="50", font="Helvetica", wrap="word")
ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
ChatLog.tag_config("right", justify="right")
ChatLog.tag_config("small", font=("Helvetica", 7))
ChatLog.tag_config("colour", foreground="#333333")
ChatLog.insert(END, current_time, ("small","colour"))
ChatLog.insert(END,textwrap.fill(f"Hello {'*Name*'}. How can I assist you?",30))
ChatLog.insert(END,'\n')
ChatLog.config(foreground="#0000CC", font=("Helvetica", 9))
ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)

# Bind scrollbar to Chat window
scrollbar = Scrollbar(base, command=ChatLog.yview, cursor="double_arrow")
ChatLog['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set

# Create Button to send message
SendButton = Button(base, font=("Comic Sans MS", 12, 'bold'), text="Send", width="8", height=5,
                    bd=0, fg="#750216", activebackground="#AAAAAA", bg="#999999", command=send_by_button)

# Create the box to enter message
EntryBox = Text(base, bd=0, fg="#000000", bg="#fff5f5", highlightcolor="#750216",
                width="29", height="5", font=("Arial",10), wrap="word")

#Placeholder config and text:
Placeholder = Text(base, bd=0, fg="#A0A0A0", bg="#fff5f5", highlightcolor="#750216",
                   width="29", height="5", font=("Arial",10), wrap="word")
Placeholder.insert("1.0", "Ask a question (i.e. What are my benefits?)")

# Place all components on the screen
scrollbar.place(x=376, y=6, height=406)
ChatLog.place(x=6, y=6, height=410, width=370)
EntryBox.place(x=6, y=421, height=70, width=276)
SendButton.place(x=282, y=421, height=70)
Placeholder.place(x=6, y=421, height=70, width=276)

Placeholder.bind("<FocusIn>", deletePlaceholder)
EntryBox.bind("<FocusOut>", addPlaceholder)


# Refresh GUI window every 0.1 seconds, mainly for the "SEND" button.
# If the entry box does not contain text --> 'Send' button is inactive, otherwise it's activated.

def update():
    global placeholderFlag
    if (EntryBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c').strip() == ''):
        SendButton['state'] = DISABLED
        placeholderFlag = 1
    elif EntryBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c').strip() != '':
        SendButton['state'] = ACTIVE
        placeholderFlag = 0
    base.after(100, update)


base.bind('<Return>', send)
update()

base.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do what you want with the `Text` widget, but you should be able to do it with a `canvas`. To keep it simple, did you consider to change the background of the *message* to create the illusion of a rectangle around it ?

Comment: @Atlas435 Can you please help me on how to redo the code using canvas instead of text? If you could just give me a little example so I can continue.

Comment: This would be a lot of code and I have my own projects to work on. Try for yourself and ask if you cant get rid of an issue. Also a possible Solution could be to use `place(x=..,y=..)` draw a shape on a transparent `canvas` or use a picture. There are many ways to get there, take some time.

Comment: You can use a label with border for the message, then use `window_create()` to insert into the text box.

Comment: @acw1668 I have tried using the method you mentioned, however I have a new problem, whenever I define my text (to be sent or received) in a `Label` widget, to add it using `window_create()`, it overwrites the previous label. Is there a solution for that?

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you so much. It finally worked. This was the best way to do without messing up all the other lines of code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acw1668 gave me a tip in the comments above so I could find a solution thanks to him. You can use the `window_create()` method in the `Text` widget.

I changed the function `send` to this and it works now:

```
def send(event):
    msg = EntryBox.get("1.0", 'end-1c').strip()
    EntryBox.delete("0.0", END)

    if msg != '':
        ChatLog.config(state=NORMAL)
        ChatLog.insert(END, current_time+' ', ("small", "right", "greycolour"))
        ChatLog.window_create(END, window=Label(ChatLog, fg="#000000", text=msg, 
        wraplength=200, font=("Arial", 10), bg="lightblue", bd=4, justify="left"))
        ChatLog.insert(END,'\n ', "left")
        ChatLog.config(foreground="#0000CC", font=("Helvetica", 9))
        ChatLog.yview(END)

        res = "Bot's response goes into here, elongating this message to test textwrap"
        ChatLog.insert(END, current_time+' ', ("small", "greycolour", "left"))
        ChatLog.window_create(END, window=Label(ChatLog, fg="#000000", text=res, 
        wraplength=200, font=("Arial", 10), bg="#DDDDDD", bd=4, justify="left"))
        ChatLog.insert(END, '\n ', "right")
        ChatLog.config(state=DISABLED)
        ChatLog.yview(END)
```

Also note that I added a new tag config to justify left:

`ChatLog.tag_config("left", justify="left")`